# Sphinx Doc - How do I render an animated GIF when building for HTML but a PNG when building for latexpdf?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

As title states, I'm using sphinx-doc and I really want to conditionally render static PNGs when the build output is latexpdf and animated GIFs when built for the web.

Ideally, it would be nice to be able to do this in the rst file itself somehow... semantically a:

if builder == html:
  .. image: blah blah
elif builder == latexpdf:
  .. image: blah blah

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [Sphinx documentation for images](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html#images):

> Sphinx extends the standard docutils behavior by allowing an asterisk for the extension:
>
> ```
> .. image:: gnu.*
> ```
>
> Sphinx then searches for all images matching the provided pattern and determines their type. Each builder then chooses the best image out of these candidates. For instance, if the file name `gnu.*` was given and two files `gnu.pdf` and `gnu.png` existed in the source tree, the LaTeX builder would choose the former, while the HTML builder would prefer the latter. Supported image types and choosing priority are defined at [Available builders](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/builders.html#builders).

To customize the "best image" order for a given builder, edit your `conf.py` to override the `StandaloneHTMLBuilder` class with the `supported_image_types` order you prefer.

```
from sphinx.builders.html import StandaloneHTMLBuilder
StandaloneHTMLBuilder.supported_image_types = [
    'image/svg+xml',
    'image/gif',
    'image/png',
    'image/jpeg'
]
```

Comment: Right I saw that but if I understand it, the HTML builder will always prefer the png image over the animated gif. Or am I missing something?

Comment: yeah, just verified that this is the case... while that fixes the latexpdf build, now the html build isn't the way I want it. :(

Comment: Ok, I figured out how to make this work...if you edit your answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer. I had to add a bit of code to monkeypatch the StandaloneHTMLBuilder class in my conf.py file by redefining the supported_image_types to put image/gif ahead of image/png

Comment: Added a mention, but you did not provide explicit code. Here's my guess `supported_image_types = ['image/gif', 'image/svg+xml', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg']`

Comment: `from sphinx.builders.html import StandaloneHTMLBuilder
StandaloneHTMLBuilder.supported_image_types = [
    'image/svg+xml', 'image/gif', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg'
]`

Answer (score 3):

In case it's useful for anyone else, I went with a variant of Steve Piercy's very helpful answer that attempts to future-proof the code and prevent mystery missing images. It uses the same structure, but appends any items that are in StandaloneHTMLBuilder.supported_image_types by default that aren't in the new set we're providing. I was considering if Sphinx started supporting something like HEIC images, or other new standards come out, this would allow them to be seamlessly integrated.

```
new_supported_image_types = [
    'image/svg+xml',
    'image/gif',
    'image/png',
    'image/jpeg'
]

# construct it this way so that if Sphinx adds default support for additional images, such
# as HEIC, then what we do is add any of those to the end. We start with the ones
# we want to support in this order, then subtract them from the defaults to identify
# any remaining items that we append to the end of the list

additional_default_supported_images = list(set(StandaloneHTMLBuilder.supported_image_types) - set(new_supported_image_types))
StandaloneHTMLBuilder.supported_image_types = new_supported_image_types + additional_default_supported_images
```